# How to get innerHTML of DIV without few inside DIV's?

Tags: javascript

I have some DIV, what contains HTML with images, styles e.t.c. I want to remove exact div's that contains id = 'quot' or className = 'quote', but i don't understand how i can get not only innerHTML of each tag. For example, < p > and < /p > which don't have innerHTML also should be included in final parsed HTML.

```
var bodytext = document.getElementById("div_text");
var NewText = "";

if (bodytext.hasChildNodes){

    var children = bodytext.childNodes;        
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        if (children[i].id != "quot" && children[i].className != "quote" && children[i].innerText != ""){
            NewText = NewText + children[i].innerHTML;
        }            
 }
```

HTML of source need to be parsed:

```
<div id="div_text">
    <p>
        Some Text</p>
    <p>
        Some Text</p>
    <p>
        <img alt="" src="localhost/i/1.png" /></p>
    <div id="quot" class="quote" />
        any text <div>text of inside div</div> 
        <table><tr><td>there can be table</td></tr></table>
    </div>

    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
    <p>
        Some Text</p>
    <p>
        Some Text</p>
    <p>
        <img alt="" src="localhost/i/1.png" /></p>        
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a javascript framework like jquery? They make tasks like this fairly trivial and you don't have to worry about cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: what is the desired output

Comment: that's invalid html. should the `</div>` near `<p>&nbsp;</p>` be '</p>'?

Comment: @Wayne fixed in first message

Comment: @ArunPJohny added desired output

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi html added

Comment: I think as Spencer Ruport said. You should use jquery

Comment: @SpencerRuport i'm zero in jQuery... I need to make all operations with variable (for future send variable into textarea without that divs). I'm trying to understand how i can work with variables in jQuery...

Comment: @black3d - If there's nothing preventing you from using it I suggest you abandon this exercise and instead concentrate on learning jQuery or some other javascript framework.

Answer (score 1):

Just grab a reference to the targeted divs and remove them from their respective parents.

Perhaps something a little like this?

**EDIT:** Added code to perform operation on a clone, rather than the document itself.
div elements don't have .getElementById method, so we search for an element manually.

```
window.addEventListener('load', myInit, false);


function removeFromDocument()
{
    // 1. take car of the element with id='quot'
    var tgt = document.getElementById('quot');
    var parentNode = tgt.parentNode;
    parentNode.removeChild(tgt);

    // 2. take care of elements whose class == 'quote'
    var tgtList = document.getElementsByClassName('quote');
    var i, n = tgtList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // we really should be checking to ensure that there aren't nested instances of matching divs
        // The following would present a problem - <div class='quote'>outer<div class='quote'>inner</div></div>
        // since the first iteration of the loop would also remove the second element in the target list,
        parentNode = tgtList[i].parentNode;
        parentNode.removeChild(tgtList[i]);
    }

    // 3. remove the containing div
    var container = document.getElementById('div_text');
    container.outerHTML = container.innerHTML;
}

function cloneAndProcess()
{
    var clonedCopy = document.getElementById('div_text').cloneNode(true);

    var tgt;// = clonedCopy.getElementById('quot');
    var i, n = clonedCopy.childNodes.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (clonedCopy.childNodes[i].id == 'quot')
        {
            tgt = clonedCopy.childNodes[i];
            var parentNode = tgt.parentNode;
            parentNode.removeChild(tgt);
            break;      // done with for loop - can only have 1 element with any given id
        }
    }

    // 2. take care of elements whose class == 'quote'
    var tgtList = clonedCopy.getElementsByClassName('quote');
    var i, n = tgtList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // we really should be checking to ensure that there aren't nested instances of matching divs
        // The following would present a problem - <div class='quote'>outer<div class='quote'>inner</div></div>
        // since the first iteration of the loop would also remove the second element in the target list,
        parentNode = tgtList[i].parentNode;
        parentNode.removeChild(tgtList[i]);
    }

    // 3. remove the containing div
    //var container = clonedCopy;   //.getElementById('div_text');
    //container.outerHTML = container.innerHTML;
    console.log(clonedCopy.innerHTML);
}


function myInit()
{
    cloneAndProcess();
    //removeFromDocument();
}
```

Comment: I need work only with variable. I mean HTML of page should be not changing, but variable should have HTML without some divs. For your code works i think i should do cloneContents (for working with nodes)?

Comment: @black3d - Ahh! Missed that part of the requirement. Yeah, that's what I'd do - do a deep-clone of the id=div_text div, then perform the above operations on the clone, rather than the document.

Comment: does exist parent node for cloned node?

Comment: Parsing by ID not working for HTML:

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="quot" style="width:90%;margin:auto;background-color:#CCCCCC">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;background-color:#EFEFEF">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <em>Quote Author</em><br />
        <p>
         <em>test</em></p>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<p>
Text1</p>
<p>
Text2</p>

Comment: @black3d - dunno. I expect it only has a parent after it's been added to the document. So, all the cloned elements would have one, except for the containing div. I'll have a look. Yeah - it seems not, which makes sense. Adding `console.log(clonedNode.parenNode);` as the last line of cloneAndProcess just prints `null` (Also - event listeners added with `.addEventListener` aren't cloned, though handlers declared inline, in the HTML are)

Comment: @black3d - just seen post re: "Parsing by ID not working for HTML: ....." - no, I wouldn't expect that it would. That's a rather different structure of html than the one you provided in your example.

Comment: you're right, sorry. But why it's not working for table? I think that should be the same structure for remove Childs <div> and <table>.

Comment: @black3d - no worries. **1.** There is no element with id=div_text. **2.** Have a look in your browser's JS debugger (Ctrl-Shift-I) **3.** Your HTML added in a comment changes this question entirely. You should edit your original post to include this (more closely representitive?) HTML. I'll look again later after dinner.

Comment: Sorry, i just didn't copy element <div id="div_text">text from note "Parsin by ID not working..."</div>

Comment: not working for 
<div class="div_text">
<div class="quote">test</div>
<p>okay,good</p>
<p>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="quote">test2</div>
<p>okay,good</p>
<p>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="quote">test3</div>
<p>okay,good</p><p>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

Comment: @black3d - no, of course it isn't. You've changed the html yet _again_. I clearly provided you with the means to clone a div whose **id** is `'div_text'`, yet you've come back and are saying that it doesn't work when the **className** is `'div_text'`. I've done al I'm prepared to do, you'll need to improve your own skills from here-on-in! Hint: document.getElementsByClassName returns a nodeList (like an array, but not quite) of elements. You'll likely want to call it with a className of `'div_text'`, followed by getting element [0] from said list. Have fun!